# where are temporary values stored in swift

Tags: swift, assembly, read-eval-print-loop

I was working with swift's REPL. I wrote a simple addition in REPL `3 + 0.14159265` and REPL returned me

```
$R2: Double = 7.54
```

when I typed back `$R2` in terminal its returned me

```
$R3: Double = 7.54
```

Are these low level registers? I have seen this in Assembly Language. There we store everything in registers instead of variables or its simple local implicit variables like php also use that `$` syntax for variables.

```
sum $r0, $t1, $t2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these are merely shortcuts for previous values from the REPL. You can inspect registers with `:register read` or `:register read --all`.